# How to set time zone with DateTime object?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I made a code that print a log in a server folder, this log return also a date with hours but the server isn't in my Nation so the hours is incorrect for me. Actually this is my code:

```
$now = new DateTime();  
$aggiornata = "\r\n" . "Aggiornamento eseguito con successo per: " . $value['caption'] . " DATA: " . $now->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
file_put_contents(getenv('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR').'php/log.txt', $aggiornata, FILE_APPEND);
```

How to set the correct hour for Italy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('now',new DateTimeZone("Europe/Rome"));
```

Comment: $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'); is also valid? Because in the log isn't printed nothing with your edit

Comment: My log file show the update time of particular season recognized by $value['caption'] parameter. I've tryed the code in localhost and the file is created, but on openshift server this code doesn't working.

Comment: well maybe it's something with your config. if it works on localhost and won't work on openshift server, it's settings

Comment: Nope it's my mistake. I closing the connection in the last class so the callback function doesn't return to the main function and the last line of code isn't executed. I've fixed anyway. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it at the top of of your file like for example:

`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');`

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in constructor as second argument

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
```

or later with `setTimezone` function

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
```

You can read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: This is unrelated issue and setting timezone in DateTime object has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Working with timezones in PHP is pretty easy. Below follows an example:

```
// Create a new DateTime object
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));

// Output
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

// Change timezone
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));

// Output again
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

Reference:

PHP Manual - [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)